# Handle Jetpack Glance widget state in a clean way

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, android-architecture-components, glance

Jetpack Glance is getting ready for stable release, I researched a lot about the best way to handle the state of widgets in a clean way in applications using Clean architecture, Hilt, MVVM, MVI and etc.
What are your suggestions for this?
One way that I saw a lot is to have key-value pairs in preferences and read them in the Widget itself, but in this way if the widget is a little bit complex it would be messy, Also in [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/glance/glance-app-widget) it is using the repository as Singletone which in our application it is usually not the case and we are using Hilt for creating that.
Let's imagine a scenario:

We have a screen that shows the weather data with a lot of information, We are using Hilt for DI and also we have Usecase, Repo, and DataSource for fetching data, Now we want to have a widget for that and it should be updated with last weather data.

```
GetWeatherUseCase -> WeatherRepository -> WeatherNetworkDataSource
```

All of these classes are provided by Hilt and use Flow and common patterns for managing data.

How we should architect a nice and clean pattern for widgets?
I think it would be an interesting topic to discuss.